# Make an element overlap contents below it using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just started playing with Twitter Bootstrap and I'm trying to make an image in a row overlap the contents below it. How can I accomplish that? I tried giving the contents below a negative margin but that doesn't seem to work in Chrome dev tools. Here's a [link](http://www.bootply.com/120416) to what I currently have, but just to summarize:

```
<div class="container" role="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/252x136" alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">  
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `<img>` pushes the entire jumbotron down. I'd like it to overlap instead until the screen size collapses (responsively) and then the image should no longer overlap in that case.

**UPDATE**

I ended up combining @JoshC and @Adrian's solutions for the best of both:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #overlap {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316391/stopping-content-from-getting-pushed-down-due-to-overlap-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could absolutely position the `.col-md-3.img` element, and then float the `.col-md-8.nav` to the right. I added some classes to the elements and then placed the styling in a media query to ensure this doesn't conflict with any mobile/tablet styling. It seems to work well on all screen sizes.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://www.bootply.com/120431) - [**FULL SCREEN EXAMPLE**](http://www.bootply.com/render/120431)

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-3.img {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
  }
  .col-md-3.img .thumbnail {
      display:inline-block;
  }
  .col-md-8.nav {
      float: right;
  }
}
```

Add `text-align:center` to center the `.thumbnail` element, which is now also `inline-block` to fix background-related issues that result from the absolute positioning.

Comment: This is strange, looks like your example link is the same as @Adrian's, did something somehow get overwritten?

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316391/stopping-content-from-getting-pushed-down-due-to-overlap-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that by adding height to your row. In the demo below, I added an id="overlap" to the row.

### [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/120425)

**CSS**

```
#overlap{
  height:90px;
}
```

Comment: That looks good but doesn't seem to work in lower screen size. I'll try combining this with @JoshC's approach.

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316391/stopping-content-from-getting-pushed-down-due-to-overlap-in-bootstrap