# Stopping content from getting pushed down due to overlap in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293227/make-an-element-overlap-contents-below-it-using-bootstrap/22293428) I was able to allow an image in one row overlap the contents below it. However, I realized that now the text and other content that is being overlapped is actually getting pushed down and ruining the format. See updated example [here](http://www.bootply.com/120751). In summary:

```
<div class="container" role="main">
  <div class="row" id="overlap">
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <!-- this is being overlapped -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #overlap {
    height: 70px;
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that the contents in the `.jumbotron` div does not get forced down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following CSS, the image should float overtop without pushing any contents down.

```
#overlap .thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Updated: http://www.bootply.com/120760

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following styles below to make it work.

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
  }
```

#### [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/120764)