# Center a div on Top of responsive image using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place a div (with some vertical buttons) over an image that is centered and responsive (this image is not the background image) Is it possible to do this with bootstrap? I still want this image to take up most of the screens width adding a caption isn't working and adding another div is moving this image from the center?

The Html for the image is as follows:

```
<div class ="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="bg2.png" class="img-responsive center-block" id="buildingimg" alt="..." >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put the code (as far as you have) for both images in the question? It currently only has code for one image.

Comment: It is not another image it is just a div width a width of "60px" and height of "200px"

Comment: Thanks, can you also show the CSS behind the `img-responsive` and `center-block` classes, in case they affect the new div?

Comment: #buildingimg {
margin-top: 0px;
} this is all I have

Comment: Can you post all the code.. the "div with some vertical buttons"

Comment: For reference [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316391/stopping-content-from-getting-pushed-down-due-to-overlap-in-bootstrap) might be a related question?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/wGRXWB

Here are some buttons in a div overlapping an image.

```
#button-overlay {position:absolute; top:0; right:0; left:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; z-index: 5; width:100%; text-align:center;}

button {width:90%; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; display:block;}

img {width:100%;}
```